# Mailmerge - connection settings vba

Tags: vba, connection, ms-word, mailmerge

I have some problem with my mailmerge macro in this part:

```
wdocSource.Mailmerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:=strWorkbookName, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    Revert:=False, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Mailing$`"
```

Can somebody help me change the `connection` settings? I am try many ways but always dont run correctly.

Comment: you code looks okay, are getting error?

Comment: yes, after few loops (one time after 15 loops, another time 166 loops) i get error `The microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ". It is already exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.`

Comment: is the file on a shared network?

Comment: No I have this folder with the files on my desktop. Do you know this problem? Is it problem with the macro?

Comment: is it possible that anyone except you is using your database while you run the macro? does anyone has access to it?

Comment: I dont have database in Microsoft Access. My data source is the excel file and nobody have access to this data. But if I change in `Data Link Properties` provider to `OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services` so it runs. So i mean that if I change the connection setting in macro it should will run.